# .Net TestContainers and Integration Tests

Tags: c#, docker, azure-pipelines, integration-testing, testcontainers

This has been driving me crazy, so any help would be much appreciated.

I have the following Azure-pipelines.yml CI pipeline:

```
  trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects: '**/*.csproj'
  BuildParameters.TestProjects: |
     $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects) 
     !**/*IntegrationTests*.csproj
     !**/*FunctionalTests*.csproj

jobs:
- job: BuildAndTest
  displayName: Build and Test

  steps:
  - task: DockerCompose@0
    displayName: "Run a Docker Compose command"
    inputs:
      dockerComposeFile: "docker-compose-integration-tests.yml"
      dockerComposeCommand: "up --abort-on-container-exit" 
    env:
      CONTAINER_NAME: 'bookywooks_orderapi_integrationtests'  

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Restore Nuget Packages 
    inputs:
       command: restore
       projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
       configuration: $(buildConfiguration)  

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/BookyWooks.sln'
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

  - script: docker --version
    displayName: 'Print Docker Version'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Run Tests
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: $(BuildParameters.TestProjects) 
      arguments: --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-build
```

The "Run a Docker Compose command" step allows my integration tests to run successfully. So this step passes. Here is the docker-compose-integration-tests.yml for that:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  # Service for running integration tests
  bookywooks_orderapi_integrationtests:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}bookywooksorderapiintegrationtests
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: BookWooks.OrderApi/src/BookWooks.OrderApi.Web/Dockerfile
      target: integrationtest  # Specify the build target
    depends_on:
      - integrationtestsdatabase  # Depends on the integration tests database service
      - rabbitmq  # Depends on the RabbitMQ service
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=integrationtestsdatabase;Database=BookyWooks.OrderDbIntegrationTests;User=sa;Password=Your_password123; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; TrustServerCertificate=true;"  # Database connection string
      - RabbitMQConfiguration__Config__HostName=${BOOKYWOOKS_RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME:-rabbitmq}  # RabbitMQ host name
      - RabbitMQConfiguration__Config__UserName=${BOOKYWOOKS_RABBITMQ_USERNAME:-guest}  # RabbitMQ user name
      - RabbitMQConfiguration__Config__Password=${BOOKYWOOKS_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD:-guest}  # RabbitMQ password
    volumes:
      - ${BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY:-./tests-results/}:/tests  # Mount volume for test results
    entrypoint:
      - dotnet  # Entry point to execute dotnet commands
      - test  # Command to run tests
      - --logger  # Specify logger options
      - trx;LogFileName=/tests/booky-wooks-integration-test-results.xml  # Use trx logger format and specify log file path

  # Service for integration tests database (SQL Server)
  integrationtestsdatabase:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"  # Use SQL Server 2022 image
    environment:
       - "SA_PASSWORD=Your_password123"  # Set SA password
       - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"  # Accept End-User License Agreement
    ports:
    -   "5433:1433"  # Map container port 1433 to host port 5433

  # Service for RabbitMQ
  rabbitmq:
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"  # Map RabbitMQ management port
      - "5672:5672"    # Map RabbitMQ port for message communication
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine  # Use RabbitMQ 3 with management plugin
```

However, I am trying to implement similar with Test Containers. That is unfortunately causing the Run Tests task of my azure-pipeline to fail. This is due to the following errors relating to connecting to RabbitMQ and SQL Server.:

```
My Rabbit MQ error is:
2024-03-12T19:14:08.6922155Z Error creating RabbitMQ connection: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
```

And Sql Server error is:

```
2024-03-12T19:14:08.9058528Z    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
```

Here is my Application Test Factory setup:

```
    public class OrderApiApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime where TEntryPoint : Program // : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{

private const string Database = "master";
private const string Username = "sa";
private const string Password = "yourStrong(!)Password";
private string _connectionString;
private const ushort MsSqlPort = 1433;
private const ushort RabbitMqPort = 5672; 
private readonly MsSqlContainer _mssqlContainer;
private readonly IContainer _rabbitMqContainer;

    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; private set; } = default!;

    private const string RabbitMqUsername = "guest";
    private const string RabbitMqPassword = "guest";

    public OrderApiApplicationFactory()
    {
   

     _mssqlContainer = new MsSqlBuilder()
    .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
    // Remove static port binding and let Docker assign random ports
    .WithPortBinding(0, MsSqlPort)
    .WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "Y") 
    .WithEnvironment("SA_PASSWORD", Password)
    .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(MsSqlPort))
    .Build();

     _rabbitMqContainer = new RabbitMqBuilder()
    .WithImage("rabbitmq:3-management-alpine") 
    .WithPortBinding(5672, RabbitMqPort) 
    .WithEnvironment("RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER", RabbitMqUsername)
    .WithEnvironment("RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS", RabbitMqPassword)
    .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer()
        .UntilPortIsAvailable(RabbitMqPort) 
        .UntilPortIsAvailable(15672)) 
    .Build();
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await _mssqlContainer.StartAsync();
        await _rabbitMqContainer.StartAsync();
       
        GetDatabaseConnectionString();

        HttpClient = CreateClient();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("testcontainersappsettings.json")
       .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
           ["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"] =  _connectionString,
           ["RabbitMQConfiguration:Config:HostName"] = _rabbitMqContainer.Hostname
       })
       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
       .Build();

            configurationBuilder.AddConfiguration(configuration);
        });

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            RemoveDbContextOptions<BookyWooksOrderDbContext>(services);
            RemoveDbContextOptions<IntegrationEventLogDbContext>(services);

            AddDbContext<BookyWooksOrderDbContext>(services);
            AddDbContext<IntegrationEventLogDbContext>(services);
        });
    }

    private void RemoveDbContextOptions<T>(IServiceCollection services) where T : DbContext
    {
        var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
            d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<T>));

        if (descriptor != null)
            services.Remove(descriptor);
    }

    private void AddDbContext<T>(IServiceCollection services) where T : DbContext
    {
        services.AddDbContext<T>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString,
                builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(T).Assembly.FullName));
        });
    }
    private string GetDatabaseConnectionString()
    {
        _connectionString = _mssqlContainer.GetConnectionString(); // $"Server={_mssqlContainer.Hostname},{_mssqlContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(MsSqlPort)};Database={Database};User Id={Username};Password={Password};TrustServerCertificate=True";
        return _connectionString;
    }

    public new async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _mssqlContainer.DisposeAsync();
        await _rabbitMqContainer.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

I believe they are set up similarly. Please note my test containers set up is working when I run the tests locally with docker but not in my azure-pipeline. Would anyone know why?

Comment: I took a brief look at your configuration, and most likely your wait strategies are wrong. Simply waiting until a port is available is usually not enough; the port might be available, but the service behind it is not ready yet. I recommend using the provided [modules](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Testcontainers) (MsSql, RabbitMq); they are pre-configured and will indicate readiness as soon as the service inside the container is truly available. Please also take a look at the [best practices](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/api/best_practices/).

Comment: You can enable the variable “[system.debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug)”(set the value to “true”) in your pipeline, then trigger a new pipeline and check if there will be more information in the debug logs.

Comment: @AndreHofmeister thank you so much. I adjusted my wait stratedgies above and that resolved the issue. That had been driving me mad for two week. So thanks again

Comment: Hi @Ports, glad to hear that you have solved the issue. so, wait UntilPortIsAvailable is not enough. Could you please share how you changed the Wait Strategy in the answer? This may benefit others who encounter this problem in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I really would like to emphasize that starting with modules (if one exists) is the best approach. Modules are pre-configured and follow the best practice configurations we usually share across different TC language implementations. If you would like to learn more about the module configuration, looking into the module's sources will help a lot. If then further customizations are necessary, using the generic builder is the way to go.